# Cannot find any Microsoft SDK libraries (Psapi, gdi32, gdiplus, etc)

Tags: windows, cmake

I would like to be able to give you more to go on, but there isn't much to say.

I'm simply doing:

```
find_library(GDIPLUS gdiplus)
find_library(GDI32 gdi32)
find_library(PSAPI psapi)
```

And I am getting:

```
GDIPLUS-NOTFOUND
GDI32-NOTFOUND
PSAPI-NOTFOUND
```

I have CMake 3.13.3 and Windows 10. I can find all these files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86` Any clues as to what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you got is that "Windows Kits" is located somewhere CMake will not look. CMake will try different methods according to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) but yet, cannot find what you are searching for.

Luckily there are ways to give hints to CMake so one way is to try adding the path to "Windows Kit" through variable CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH:

> cmake -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86

Quotes(") might be necessary around the path name since you are using windows.